# Entity Framework 6 - Form relationship using object which doesn't exist in the DB yet

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Suppose a Company has Employees. Company 'Solutions' has Employee 'James'.

These entities are both saved in the DB, and their relationship is expressed through a foreign key.

At the application level, the Employee class has a Company object property, to define the relationship.

Suppose a new company 'Better Solutions' is created, which doesn't exist in the DB yet, and James now moves to this company.

How do I tell EF to handle this? Currently I:

Save the new company 'Better Solutions' (object created with a GUID ID) to the DB:

```
db.Companies.Add(newCompany);
```

Change the Company property on Jame's instance:

```
james.Company = newCompany;
```

Tell EF that a property on James's instance has changed and needs updating:

```
db.Employees.Attach(james);
db.Entry(james).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
```

But when this happens, the `newCompany` object doesn't have its new database ID yet (even though it's been added to the database, the object still holds the GUID ID), so when saving EF tries to do this:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[Employee]
SET [CompanyID] = SomeGUID, 
WHERE ([EmployeeID] = JamesID)
```

Which of course throws an exception because no CompanyID matches that GUID:

```
The UPDATE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
```

In this scenario, do I need to first push the newCompany object to the DB, then retrieve it from the DB (to get the new ID), then set this retrieved object as James's Company property?

Or does EF have a cleaner way of taking care of all this?

Comment: so here thing you have to do is 
1. Insert new company into the database. Then call save changes
2. After insertions the newcompany object will get updated with the id that is being generated 
3. Then assign that newcompany id to employee or directly assign new company to employee and save the changes. This will work

Comment: Does Employee have a CompanyId property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to do like below. Save company first then assign it to james that will update existing employee.

`db.Companies.Add(newCompany); 
 db.SaveChanges();
 james.Company = newCompany;
 db.SaveChanges();`

Comment: Oh thank you this is simple. The problem I had was with the mapping between business logic and DAL levels, so the new automatically updated ID was lost when I went back to the business logic. But this is something for me to sort out.

Comment: Note that this is not transactional.

Comment: @GertArnold Indeed. And is more like quick-and-dirty workaround rather than a solution.

Comment: @IvanStoev I agree. I'd rather work out a solution with stub entities, but that takes a bit more time (which I don't have right now).